# mac osx script - find mounted disc with name, copy file from desktop to it, when copy complete, unmount disc

Tags: macos, mac, script, automator

Is there some kind of mac script which finds a newly mounted disc drive that has the name 'EXAMPLE', then copies a file/folder to it and safely ejects the disc when copy has finished?

I don't mind if the script needs to be executed by a short cut.

And will it work if there are multiple drives plugged in?

The reason I am asking is becuase i have 5000 usb memory sticks that I need to copy about 20mb worth of data to it.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a command like like this in Terminal:

```
cp -R /path/to/folder /Volumes/EXAMPLE;diskutil eject /Volumes/EXAMPLE
```

Comment: Cool let me have a play

Comment: This works but I am struggling with the path to my folder on the desktop - the find and eject bit works but can't copy. What would I put if I needed to get a folder called '2014 Files' which is on my desktop?